# Codenameone Settings when connecting to iTunes

Tags: codenameone

I see pop-up error saying failed to send the code. sockets closed unexpectedly. Please advise if anyone see this issue along with error message saying internal CLI error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only have one device connected to Apple in their 2 factor authentication. Assuming that's the case it should work. We are working on addressing some additional issues.

Comment: on a different note, is there a disabling two-factor authentication on iTunes Connect from Codename Settings.  Every time it asks for two factor authentication and after entering the code it shows error message "failed to send the code. sockets closed unexpectedly"

Comment: You can't disable two factor anymore. Apple no longer allows it. You need to have exactly one device connected to 2fa for it to work. We're looking at updating the servers to solve some login edge cases so if it still doesn't work hopefully it will just start working over this weekend.

Comment: What are the steps to take after upgrading the servers. How can I update on Netbeans. Please advise.

Comment: If we're able to improve this it should "just work" as the client communicates with our webservice which communicates with Apple. So we only fix the servers and things improve. AFAIK this fix didn't make it this weekend but unlike the other work we do it isn't bound by our weekly update policy.

Comment: Ok Shai. I still this error though. How can I access the error log.What is location of the error log.

Comment: This is our log, we can access it now that you provided the code